Can I use a series of linear regressions to perform post-hoc tests on survey data in R following a comparison of means for 3+ variables?
Thomas Lumley explained within this StackOverflow post that the survey package's regTermTest() function can be used to compare means of 3+ groups. However, I would like to clarify what post-hoc test(s) to use in the event that this test reveals a statistically significant difference between the means. Would a series of linear regressions make sense here, and if so, would I need to apply a correction to account for the multiple tests I'm performing?
For example, let's say that I am analyzing differences in household income among Republicans, Democrats, and Independents within a weighted survey dataset. My regTermTest() results indicate a significant difference between these groups; however, I'll then want to determine whether the difference in income between (1) Republicans and Democrats, (2) Republicans and Independents, and (3) Democrats and Independents are statistically significant.
I believe I could answer these follow-up questions by performing two regressions, one with Republicans as the intercept and the other with Democrats as the intercept, and then analyzing the statistical significance of the coefficients I retrieve. (This method was inspired by Chapter 7 of Exploring Complex Survey Data Analysis in R.) However, given that I'm performing two different tests here, would I then need to use a Holm or Bonferroni correction to reduce the chance of a Type I error?
(Come to think of it: Could I just skip the initial regTermTest and go directly to these linear regressions, or would it first be important to make sure that the means of these three groups actually differ?
Also, would pairwise T tests be a better alternative to these post-hoc regressions, or would the results output by that test be the same?
